How to design a 2nd order low pass filter
I have a question about second order low pass filters.
I have a DC/DC power supply at 3.3 V and I would like to filter this signal to address any disturbance from 50 Hz (ideally only keep the DC component).
I would like to know what is the difference between RLC filters and RC cascades.
Do you have any advice on the best types of filters to put in place because I want it to be quite restrictive in terms of frequency.
Do you know of other second-order low-pass filter structures that could be implemented to filter a DC power signal?
Thank you in advance for your answers

I think you may be better served with a voltage regulator.

unfortunately the current consumed is too high and I also have a space constraint (I forgot to mention it).

@MisterElec94 High current and filtering out 50 Hz means dissipation or else energy storage and release. Either of these choices involves space. And potentially a fair bit of it. We'd need to see exactly what you are getting right now and at what currents/loading, to get an idea of just how much dissipation or energy storage is needed. But I would not bet on it living within a small space constraint.

This tool seems to work for designing low pass filters. https://markimicrowave.com/technical-resources/tools/lc-filter-design-tool/. I had checked it with LT spice and the frequency response is pretty accurate

How much current at 3.3V you need? What is the level of 50 Hz ripple now and how much you need it to be? No ripple at all means infinite value components so you need to define an acceptable level.

at 3.3 V i need approximately 1.5 -1.6 A

If you are looking into filtering a power rail (with non negligible current), I would advice against using any filter containing a resistor in series with your load (it will cause a voltage drop, and a loss of power).
Instead, I would advice you look into filters based on inductors in series with your load, and capacitors in parallel to your load. Those, with ideal components, don't dissipate any of the power from the DC component of your signal (in practice you still have some losses due to parasitic resistance of inductors and ESR of capacitors).
So you can look into LC filters, as well as pi and T filters (ie filters with 2 capacitors and 1 inductor or 2 inductors and 1 capacitor).
Even simpler, you can often reduce the noise from the DC/DC by simply adding a capacitor in parallel to its output. Please check beforehand the maximum output capacitance supported by your DC/DC supply.
PS : I'm quite surprised you have problems with 50Hz on a DC/DC. There shouldn't be any (or much) 50Hz signal on the input side in the first place (excepted if it's not real DC, but just rectified AC), and a decent DC/DC should be quite good at rejecting anything as low frequency as 50Hz. So if your input is rectified AC, and you still get plenty of 50Hz (or 100Hz) on the output, you probably didn't choose a decent DC/DC (or forgot to add a big enough capacitor at the input side of the DC/DC)

small clarification: the regulator is not on the card or the signal must be filtered and I do not have access to this regulator. I would like to filter all frequencies potentially disruptive to the power supply because I have no certainty about the environment where my card will be placed. that's why I included the 50 Hz.

If you can afford it (from cost, space and efficiency perspectives), you can add a buck-boost converter (or a buck converter or a linear regulator if you can accept a lower output voltage), and therefore ensure a well regulated voltage whatever you input is. You can also restrict filtering for the few components for which noise is an issue, and supply the rest with your "dirty" 3.3V

Do you think that placing a ferrite would allow me to just keep the DC component of my signal without degrading it?

A ferrite might help for high frequency noise (nb : make sure to choose one with low DC resistance), but I don't expect it will help for 50Hz noise

Do you think that putting two RCs in series would allow me to be able to filter without having too large component values?

How much current do you expect to draw from your supplies? If more than a few tens of mA, then RC filters is a really bad idea (you will have a significant voltage drop across your resistor, excepted if you use a very small resistor, in which case the capacitors will be insanely big).

Using 2 RC (or better LC) filters instead of one will not move the cutting frequency by much (it's the cutting frequency is fc=RC or fc=1/LC for 1st order RC or LC filters, so it will dictate the size of the capacitors). So using a 2 stage filter will not influance much on the smallest frequency that you reject. It will however enable to attenuate more the frequencies that are attenuated.

If you care about 50Hz, then tell us the current you need, so we can tell you if a filter might be an option, or not (in which case you need a regulator, for which 50Hz should be slow enough to be no problem). The question has been closed for a reason : we need much more details if you want a good answer

I need 3.3 V at around 1.5 A

at this current ratings, your resistor (on resistance of your inductor) would need to be very small (like R=0.2 ohms if you can accept 0.3V voltage drop). So If you want a cutting frequency of fc=5Hz (ie one order of agnitude bellow the 50Hz you want to attenuate), you need fc=1/(2piRC), ie C= 1/ (2piRfc) = 0.16F : it's starting to get quite big! (and you are just dividing the amplitude of the 50Hz by about 10)
